# Actionbar visibility listener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment, android-youtube-api

Is there any way to listen if `actionbar` is invisible or visible.(a callback/listener method). `"isShowing()"` not working in my cases.

My Case :
I've a YouTube player in full screen mode with overlaying an actionbar (android.support.v7.app.ActionBar) and a dialog fragment added at bottom of the screen. Now, I need a listener to hide and show that dialog fragment, but there have no such listener in youtube player api. So, I'm trying to get it through inheriting actionbar visibility. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a listener if actionbar is now Visible or Invisible.

Comment: Can an `ActionBar` be invisible or visible without you doing that in Code! Or what type of `ActionBar` you are talking about!

Comment: off course with code :P , please check the updated question considering my cases. thanks

Comment: If you get that ActionBar from you tube Api can you access it?

Comment: No, I can access it from my activity, it just overlayed with the player . If player controls get hided actionbar also get hided as well. BUT I can get only actionbar is visible or invisible with "getSupportActionBar().isShowing()" during activity creation. Which not solving my cases, a listener is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create two functions in activity

```
    void showActionbar() { getSupportActionBar().show(); }
    void hideActionbar() { getSupportActionBar().hide(); }
```

Call them in your fragment when you want to show or hide. Here is how you call

```
    ((ActivityName)getActivity()).showActionbar();
    ((ActivityName)getActivity()).hideActionbar();
```

You can also check if actionbar showing with

```
    boolean IsActionbarVisible() { if(getSupportActionBar().isShowing())
    return true;  else return false; }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, Please elaborate little more so that i can help.